# How to select rows comparing multiple columns with the same value?

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have the following data and a vector of column names

```
dt <- data.table(id = letters[1:10], amount = 1:10, id2 = c(rep('a',5),rep('b',5)),test=rep('a',10))
cols <- c('id','id2','test')
```

what I'm trying to do is select rows where all columns in the vector have the same specific value like

```
dt[id=='a' & id2=='a' & test == 'a']
```

but using the vector `cols`. Is there a way to do it?

**Note:** I need to find a way to do it using `data.table` or `base R` without making comparisons between the columns like

```
dt[id==id2 & id==test & id2==test]
```

Comment: Does `dt` need to be a data.table or can we use dataframe as well?

Comment: @elielink need to be a `data.table`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take help of `.SDcols` -

```
library(data.table)

dt[dt[, rowSums(.SD == 'a') == length(cols), .SDcols = cols]]

#   id amount id2 test
#1:  a      1   a    a
```

This can also be written as -

```
dt[rowSums(dt[, ..cols] == 'a') == length(cols), ]
```

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr` and `purrr`, you could do:

```
dt %>%
    filter(reduce(.x = across(all_of(cols), ~ . == "a"), .f = `&`))

   id amount id2 test
1:  a      1   a    a
```

Or the same idea using `data.table`:

```
dt[dt[, Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, function(x) x == "a")), .SDcols = cols]]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I forgot to write that I'm looking for a solution using `data.table` or `base R`to not mix packages

Comment: Updated it with the `data.table` equivalent :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `data.table`-friendly solution that is not looking for the literal `"a"`:

This helper-function simply takes the `table` of its arguments, and returns `TRUE` if the number of distinct elements is other than "1". (I test for `2L` because I use `useNA="always"`, which will always append an `NA` count even if 0.)

```r
allsame <- function(x) do.call(mapply, c(list(FUN = function(...) length(table(unlist(list(...)), useNA = "always")) == 2L), x))
```

From here, you can use it externally or internally:

```r
dt[allsame(dt[,..cols]),]
#        id amount    id2   test
#    <char>  <int> <char> <char>
# 1:      a      1      a      a
```

It's in fact not `data.table`-specific, it'll work with anything as long as its argument is a `data.frame`-like object with all of the comments you need compared.

```r
mtcars[1:3,10:11]
#               gear carb
# Mazda RX4        4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag    4    4
# Datsun 710       4    1

allsame(mtcars[1:3,10:11])
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using a join:

```
dt[as.list(rep('a', length(cols))), on=cols]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `if_all`

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
    filter(if_all(all_of(cols), ~ . == 'a'))
   id amount id2 test
1:  a      1   a    a
```